# Plott a DAG in a dot layout using ggnet

Tags: r, layout, graph, ggplot2

Is there a way to plot a DAG in a `dot` layout (a-la `Rgraphviz`) using `ggnet`?

My example is a Gene Ontology graph, taken from [`topGO`'s `vignette`](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/topGO/inst/doc/topGO.pdf):

```
  library(topGO)
  library(ALL)
  data(ALL)
  data(geneList)
  affyLib <- paste(annotation(ALL),"db",sep= ".")
  library(package=affyLib,character.only=TRUE)
  topgo.obj <- new("topGOdata",description="Simple session",ontology="BP",allGenes=geneList,geneSel=topDiffGenes,nodeSize=10,annot=annFUN.db,affyLib=affyLib)
  res.fisher <- runTest(topgo.obj,algorithm="classic",statistic="fisher")
  res.df <- GenTable(topgo.obj,classicFisher=res.fisher,orderBy="classicFisher",topNodes=length(score(res.fisher)))
```

For convenience I set:

```
res.df$p.value <- as.numeric(res.df$classicFisher)
```

I keep in the `topGO` `graphNEL` only nodes that have p-values below 0.05, and their ancestors:

```
topgo.graph <- graph(topgo.obj)
sig.cutoff <- 0.05
sig.node.names <- dplyr::filter(res.df,p.value < sig.cutoff)$GO.ID
topgo.graph <- reverseArch(inducedGraph(topgo.graph,sig.node.names))
```

To use `ggnet` I convert the `graphNEL` graph to an `igraph`:

```
  library(ggnet)
  library(network)
  library(sna)
  library(scales)
  library(igraph)
  library(intergraph)

  topgo.igraph <- graph_from_graphnel(topgo.graph,name=TRUE,weight=TRUE,unlist.attrs=TRUE)
  topgo.network <- asNetwork(topgo.igraph,amap=attrmap())
  ggnet2(net=topgo.network,size=10,arrow.size=12,arrow.gap=0.025)
```

which gives me this:
[image]

Using `Rgraphviz`'s `dot` layout is the format I'd like `ggnet` to print it out in:

```
library(Rgraphviz) 

nodeAttrs <- list()
edgeAttrs <- list()
graphAttrs <- getDefaultAttrs(layoutType='dot')
graphAttrs$cluster <- NULL
graphAttrs$node$shape <- 'box'
graphAttrs$node$fontsize <- '14'
nodeAttrs$label <- nodes(topgo.graph)
names(nodeAttrs$label) <- nodes(topgo.graph)
graphAttrs$edge$color <- 'black'

plot(agopen(graph=topgo.graph,name="GO",attrs=graphAttrs,nodeAttrs=nodeAttrs,edgeAttrs=edgeAttrs))
```

So my question is how can I get ggnet to plot topgo.network in this layout?

[image]

Comment: I made a mistake adding this to my previous question, which was about converting a graphNEL graph to a netwrok graph. I'm editing that question back to what it was.

Comment: Why can't you use `showSigOfNodes` as in the vignette? Because you only want the relationship between the significant GO?